# Dynamic loaded controls in PlaceHolder via UpdatePanel (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, webforms

On page, after selected in ComboBox control, i loading controls in Placeholder via an UpdatePanel. But after sending postback, there aren't this controls in a Placeholder.controls loop.

How can i create dynamic controls without reload page and get values in postback?

Ex: Combobox of categories and after selected, loading features of this category.
thnx

Answer (score 0):

The controls must be re-added with post back, or you won't be able to get the values from the controls.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the Controls int the OnInit EventHandler (everytime), and assign Data to those controls during the OnLoad Event.